# Can I get transacntion hash of any triggered function of smart contract in solidity?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

Essentially, my goal is to obtain the transaction hash, which is a unique identifier used to check the status of a transaction on a blockchain explorer, such as etherscan.io. I want to obtain this hash for any trigger function in a smart contract.

I know, I can get this after calling that perticular function of smart contract during intergration and get hash but I want the same thing in solidity.

I try by

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import "patient.sol";

contract Doctor_Contract is Patient_Contract {

```
struct Doctor {
    string doctor_name;
    string doctor_email;
    uint32 d_phone_no;
    uint32 doctor_id;
    bytes32 hash;
}
uint32 doctor_id = 1;

Doctor[] doctor_record;


function AddDoctorRecord(string memory doctor_name, string memory doctor_email, 
uint32 d_phone_no ) public onlyadmin {
    bytes32 _hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, block.timestamp, block.difficulty));
    doctor_record.push(Doctor( doctor_name, doctor_email, d_phone_no,doctor_id,_hash));
    doctor_id++;
}

function GetDoctorRecord() public view returns(Doctor[] memory){
    
    return(doctor_record);
    
    
}
```

}

In the above code I used keccak256 for getting the same hash but I got wrong on it.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me?  Even if you were able to obtain the transaction hash, it would obviously be still execute since your code is still executing.  You wouldn't be able to query it from solidity, because Oracles have to push to your contract not vice vera

Comment: Why don't you post what you real end goal is with the code and not what you're trying to do it meet it

Comment: [Please read xyproblem.info on how to ask questions](https://xyproblem.info/)